# Fill in NaN values in dataframe intervals according to conditions of a column

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe with me which has an ID column and description column with START and STOP values  represented by the ID's. Every START-STOP pair is denoted by an ID and it is incremented to 1 on next appearance of the pair.

[image: Initial Dataframe]

**I need to increment the ID by 1 right after the STOP element has occured (update the NaN's of course) and this same ID should continue till I find the next STOP**.
Also how to take care of the *first START-STOP pair* since the main problem focuses on covering STOP-STOP event?
Also, any number of events or segments can be there inside the START-STOP or a STOP-STOP pair

I would like to have like this in the end

[image: output dataframe]

This kind of needs to be applied for hundreds of thousands of rows and not a bunch of rows shown as sample. Kindly help me on this! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
# create a group-tag by every STOP
cond = df.SEG_DESC == 'STOP'
df['tag'] = cond.cumsum()
df.loc[cond, 'tag'] = df.loc[cond, 'tag'] - 1

# for every tag-group use back fillna
df['ID_START_STOP'] = df.groupby('tag')['ID_START_STOP'].bfill().astype(int)
```